# Popup div with pure CSS/HTML without changing the viewport position

Tags: html, css, popup, popupwindow

What I am trying to implement is a popup window with pure CSS, i.e. without using JavaScript. I have come up with a solution using the `target` pseudoclass, but the problem is that whenever I click the `close` button of the popup, it scrolls the viewport to the `href` element I specified, in this case `#home`. What I want to achieve is a functionality where the viewport doesn't move, regardless of the scroll position. For example, if I open the popup and then scroll to the last section, and then click the close button, the viewport should stay at the last section.

Here is jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tmzjpwkz/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace href with   #popup:target

```
  <a href="#popup:target">Close</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tmzjpwkz/8/